# Finding all possible pythagorean triangles within a set of triangles

Tags: c++, iteration, cout, pythagorean, triangle-count

I've looked at this thread: [All possible Pythagorean Triples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500037/all-possible-pythagorean-triples)
Looks similar to mine but I can't get mine to work for some reason..

#### REVISION 1

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Labb2_uppg1 {
public:
    void run() {
        compute();
    }
private:
void compute() {                                                            // performs the computations
    int a, b, c, counter = 0, counter_pyth = 0;                             // a = cathetus of triangle
                                                                            // b = cathetus of triangle
                                                                            // c = hypotenuse of triangle
                                                                            // counter = used to determine the amount of iterated triangles
                                                                            // counter_pyth = used to determine the subset of pythagorean triangles in the total amount of iterated triangles
    for (a = 1; a <= 500; a++) {
        for (b = a; b <= 500; b++) {                                        // starts from the same index as 'a' to omit duplicate results
            counter++;
            c = int_sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
            if (c == 100 || c == 200 || c == 300 || c == 400 || c == 500)   // prints the triangles whose hypotenuse matches the integers 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500
                cout << "Triangel med hypotenusan " << c << ": a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;
            if (((a*a)+(b*b))==(c*c)) {
                cout << "DEBUG_01: a = " << a << ", b = " << b
                        << ", c = " << c << endl;
                counter_pyth++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nAntal itererade trianglar: " << counter;                     // prints the number of triangles that the program has iterated through
    cout << "\nAntal pytagoreiska trianglar: " << counter_pyth << "\n\n";   // prints the number of Pythagorean triangles that the program has iterated through
}

int int_sqrt(int r) {                                                       // simplification of the Bakhsali Approximation method to calculate square roots
                                                                            // only integers may be used when invoking this function
                                                                            // returns the integer square root if it was successfully calculated using the radicand r
    int i = 0;                                                              // initiates 'i' to a value of 0
    while ((i*i) <= r)                                                      // approximates the square of 'i' to the radicand 'r'
        i++;
    i--;

    if ((i*i) == r)                                                         // if the square of 'i' is exactly 'r'
        return i;                                                           // then the integer root of 'r' has successfully been found
    else
        return -1;                                                          // else -1 is returned, no real number (radicand) can have -1 as its root
    }

};
```

#### Output:

```
DEBUG_01: a = 95, b = 228, c = 247
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 110, c = 146
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 128, c = 160
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 180, c = 204
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 247, c = 265
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 280, c = 296
DEBUG_01: a = 96, b = 378, c = 390
DEBUG_01: a = 98, b = 336, c = 350
DEBUG_01: a = 99, b = 132, c = 165
DEBUG_01: a = 99, b = 168, c = 195
DEBUG_01: a = 99, b = 440, c = 451
DEBUG_01: a = 100, b = 105, c = 145
DEBUG_01: a = 100, b = 240, c = 260
DEBUG_01: a = 100, b = 495, c = 505
DEBUG_01: a = 102, b = 136, c = 170
DEBUG_01: a = 102, b = 280, c = 298
DEBUG_01: a = 104, b = 153, c = 185
DEBUG_01: a = 104, b = 195, c = 221
DEBUG_01: a = 104, b = 330, c = 346
DEBUG_01: a = 105, b = 140, c = 175
DEBUG_01: a = 105, b = 208, c = 233
DEBUG_01: a = 105, b = 252, c = 273
DEBUG_01: a = 105, b = 360, c = 375
DEBUG_01: a = 108, b = 144, c = 180
DEBUG_01: a = 108, b = 231, c = 255
DEBUG_01: a = 108, b = 315, c = 333
DEBUG_01: a = 108, b = 480, c = 492
DEBUG_01: a = 110, b = 264, c = 286
DEBUG_01: a = 111, b = 148, c = 185
DEBUG_01: a = 112, b = 180, c = 212
DEBUG_01: a = 112, b = 210, c = 238
Triangel med hypotenusan 400: a = 112, b = 384
DEBUG_01: a = 112, b = 384, c = 400
DEBUG_01: a = 112, b = 441, c = 455
DEBUG_01: a = 114, b = 152, c = 190
DEBUG_01: a = 114, b = 352, c = 370
DEBUG_01: a = 115, b = 252, c = 277
DEBUG_01: a = 115, b = 276, c = 299
DEBUG_01: a = 117, b = 156, c = 195
DEBUG_01: a = 117, b = 240, c = 267
DEBUG_01: a = 119, b = 120, c = 169
DEBUG_01: a = 119, b = 408, c = 425
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 126, c = 174
Triangel med hypotenusan 200: a = 120, b = 160
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 160, c = 200
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 182, c = 218
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 209, c = 241
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 225, c = 255
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 288, c = 312
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 350, c = 370
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 391, c = 409
DEBUG_01: a = 120, b = 442, c = 458
DEBUG_01: a = 123, b = 164, c = 205
DEBUG_01: a = 125, b = 300, c = 325
DEBUG_01: a = 126, b = 168, c = 210
DEBUG_01: a = 126, b = 432, c = 450
DEBUG_01: a = 128, b = 240, c = 272
DEBUG_01: a = 129, b = 172, c = 215
DEBUG_01: a = 130, b = 144, c = 194
DEBUG_01: a = 130, b = 312, c = 338
DEBUG_01: a = 132, b = 176, c = 220
DEBUG_01: a = 132, b = 224, c = 260
DEBUG_01: a = 132, b = 351, c = 375
DEBUG_01: a = 132, b = 385, c = 407
DEBUG_01: a = 132, b = 475, c = 493
DEBUG_01: a = 133, b = 156, c = 205
DEBUG_01: a = 133, b = 456, c = 475
DEBUG_01: a = 135, b = 180, c = 225
DEBUG_01: a = 135, b = 324, c = 351
DEBUG_01: a = 135, b = 352, c = 377
DEBUG_01: a = 136, b = 255, c = 289
DEBUG_01: a = 136, b = 273, c = 305
DEBUG_01: a = 138, b = 184, c = 230
DEBUG_01: a = 140, b = 147, c = 203
DEBUG_01: a = 140, b = 171, c = 221
DEBUG_01: a = 140, b = 225, c = 265
DEBUG_01: a = 140, b = 336, c = 364
Triangel med hypotenusan 500: a = 140, b = 480
DEBUG_01: a = 140, b = 480, c = 500
DEBUG_01: a = 141, b = 188, c = 235
DEBUG_01: a = 144, b = 165, c = 219
DEBUG_01: a = 144, b = 192, c = 240
DEBUG_01: a = 144, b = 270, c = 306
DEBUG_01: a = 144, b = 308, c = 340
DEBUG_01: a = 144, b = 420, c = 444
DEBUG_01: a = 145, b = 348, c = 377
DEBUG_01: a = 145, b = 408, c = 433
DEBUG_01: a = 147, b = 196, c = 245
DEBUG_01: a = 150, b = 200, c = 250
DEBUG_01: a = 150, b = 360, c = 390
DEBUG_01: a = 152, b = 285, c = 323
DEBUG_01: a = 152, b = 345, c = 377
DEBUG_01: a = 153, b = 204, c = 255
DEBUG_01: a = 153, b = 420, c = 447
DEBUG_01: a = 155, b = 372, c = 403
DEBUG_01: a = 155, b = 468, c = 493
DEBUG_01: a = 156, b = 208, c = 260
DEBUG_01: a = 156, b = 320, c = 356
DEBUG_01: a = 156, b = 455, c = 481
DEBUG_01: a = 156, b = 495, c = 519
DEBUG_01: a = 159, b = 212, c = 265
DEBUG_01: a = 160, b = 168, c = 232
DEBUG_01: a = 160, b = 231, c = 281
DEBUG_01: a = 160, b = 300, c = 340
DEBUG_01: a = 160, b = 384, c = 416
DEBUG_01: a = 161, b = 240, c = 289
DEBUG_01: a = 162, b = 216, c = 270
DEBUG_01: a = 165, b = 220, c = 275
DEBUG_01: a = 165, b = 280, c = 325
DEBUG_01: a = 165, b = 396, c = 429
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 224, c = 280
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 270, c = 318
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 315, c = 357
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 374, c = 410
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 425, c = 457
DEBUG_01: a = 168, b = 490, c = 518
DEBUG_01: a = 170, b = 264, c = 314
DEBUG_01: a = 170, b = 408, c = 442
DEBUG_01: a = 171, b = 228, c = 285
DEBUG_01: a = 174, b = 232, c = 290
DEBUG_01: a = 175, b = 288, c = 337
DEBUG_01: a = 175, b = 420, c = 455
DEBUG_01: a = 176, b = 210, c = 274
DEBUG_01: a = 176, b = 330, c = 374
Triangel med hypotenusan 500: a = 176, b = 468
DEBUG_01: a = 176, b = 468, c = 500
DEBUG_01: a = 177, b = 236, c = 295
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 189, c = 261
Triangel med hypotenusan 300: a = 180, b = 240
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 240, c = 300
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 273, c = 327
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 299, c = 349
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 385, c = 425
DEBUG_01: a = 180, b = 432, c = 468
DEBUG_01: a = 183, b = 244, c = 305
DEBUG_01: a = 184, b = 345, c = 391
DEBUG_01: a = 185, b = 444, c = 481
DEBUG_01: a = 186, b = 248, c = 310
DEBUG_01: a = 189, b = 252, c = 315
DEBUG_01: a = 189, b = 340, c = 389
DEBUG_01: a = 190, b = 336, c = 386
DEBUG_01: a = 190, b = 456, c = 494
DEBUG_01: a = 192, b = 220, c = 292
DEBUG_01: a = 192, b = 256, c = 320
DEBUG_01: a = 192, b = 360, c = 408
DEBUG_01: a = 192, b = 494, c = 530
DEBUG_01: a = 195, b = 216, c = 291
DEBUG_01: a = 195, b = 260, c = 325
DEBUG_01: a = 195, b = 400, c = 445
DEBUG_01: a = 195, b = 468, c = 507
DEBUG_01: a = 196, b = 315, c = 371
DEBUG_01: a = 198, b = 264, c = 330
DEBUG_01: a = 198, b = 336, c = 390
DEBUG_01: a = 200, b = 210, c = 290
DEBUG_01: a = 200, b = 375, c = 425
DEBUG_01: a = 200, b = 480, c = 520
DEBUG_01: a = 201, b = 268, c = 335
DEBUG_01: a = 203, b = 396, c = 445
DEBUG_01: a = 204, b = 253, c = 325
DEBUG_01: a = 204, b = 272, c = 340
DEBUG_01: a = 205, b = 492, c = 533
DEBUG_01: a = 207, b = 224, c = 305
DEBUG_01: a = 207, b = 276, c = 345
DEBUG_01: a = 208, b = 306, c = 370
DEBUG_01: a = 208, b = 390, c = 442
DEBUG_01: a = 210, b = 280, c = 350
DEBUG_01: a = 210, b = 416, c = 466
DEBUG_01: a = 213, b = 284, c = 355
DEBUG_01: a = 216, b = 288, c = 360
DEBUG_01: a = 216, b = 405, c = 459
DEBUG_01: a = 216, b = 462, c = 510
DEBUG_01: a = 217, b = 456, c = 505
DEBUG_01: a = 219, b = 292, c = 365
DEBUG_01: a = 220, b = 231, c = 319
DEBUG_01: a = 220, b = 459, c = 509
DEBUG_01: a = 222, b = 296, c = 370
DEBUG_01: a = 224, b = 360, c = 424
DEBUG_01: a = 224, b = 420, c = 476
DEBUG_01: a = 225, b = 272, c = 353
DEBUG_01: a = 225, b = 300, c = 375
DEBUG_01: a = 228, b = 304, c = 380
DEBUG_01: a = 228, b = 325, c = 397
DEBUG_01: a = 231, b = 308, c = 385
DEBUG_01: a = 231, b = 392, c = 455
DEBUG_01: a = 232, b = 435, c = 493
DEBUG_01: a = 234, b = 312, c = 390
DEBUG_01: a = 234, b = 480, c = 534
DEBUG_01: a = 237, b = 316, c = 395
DEBUG_01: a = 238, b = 240, c = 338
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 252, c = 348
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 275, c = 365
Triangel med hypotenusan 400: a = 240, b = 320
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 320, c = 400
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 364, c = 436
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 418, c = 482
DEBUG_01: a = 240, b = 450, c = 510
DEBUG_01: a = 243, b = 324, c = 405
DEBUG_01: a = 246, b = 328, c = 410
DEBUG_01: a = 248, b = 465, c = 527
DEBUG_01: a = 249, b = 332, c = 415
DEBUG_01: a = 252, b = 275, c = 373
DEBUG_01: a = 252, b = 336, c = 420
DEBUG_01: a = 252, b = 405, c = 477
DEBUG_01: a = 255, b = 340, c = 425
DEBUG_01: a = 255, b = 396, c = 471
DEBUG_01: a = 256, b = 480, c = 544
DEBUG_01: a = 258, b = 344, c = 430
DEBUG_01: a = 260, b = 273, c = 377
DEBUG_01: a = 260, b = 288, c = 388
DEBUG_01: a = 261, b = 348, c = 435
DEBUG_01: a = 261, b = 380, c = 461
DEBUG_01: a = 264, b = 315, c = 411
DEBUG_01: a = 264, b = 352, c = 440
DEBUG_01: a = 264, b = 448, c = 520
DEBUG_01: a = 264, b = 495, c = 561
DEBUG_01: a = 266, b = 312, c = 410
DEBUG_01: a = 267, b = 356, c = 445
DEBUG_01: a = 270, b = 360, c = 450
DEBUG_01: a = 273, b = 364, c = 455
DEBUG_01: a = 276, b = 368, c = 460
DEBUG_01: a = 276, b = 493, c = 565
DEBUG_01: a = 279, b = 372, c = 465
DEBUG_01: a = 279, b = 440, c = 521
DEBUG_01: a = 280, b = 294, c = 406
DEBUG_01: a = 280, b = 342, c = 442
DEBUG_01: a = 280, b = 351, c = 449
DEBUG_01: a = 280, b = 450, c = 530
DEBUG_01: a = 282, b = 376, c = 470
DEBUG_01: a = 285, b = 380, c = 475
DEBUG_01: a = 288, b = 330, c = 438
DEBUG_01: a = 288, b = 384, c = 480
DEBUG_01: a = 291, b = 388, c = 485
DEBUG_01: a = 294, b = 392, c = 490
DEBUG_01: a = 297, b = 304, c = 425
DEBUG_01: a = 297, b = 396, c = 495
DEBUG_01: a = 300, b = 315, c = 435
Triangel med hypotenusan 500: a = 300, b = 400
DEBUG_01: a = 300, b = 400, c = 500
DEBUG_01: a = 300, b = 455, c = 545
DEBUG_01: a = 303, b = 404, c = 505
DEBUG_01: a = 306, b = 408, c = 510
DEBUG_01: a = 308, b = 435, c = 533
DEBUG_01: a = 308, b = 495, c = 583
DEBUG_01: a = 309, b = 412, c = 515
DEBUG_01: a = 312, b = 416, c = 520
DEBUG_01: a = 312, b = 459, c = 555
DEBUG_01: a = 315, b = 420, c = 525
DEBUG_01: a = 318, b = 424, c = 530
DEBUG_01: a = 319, b = 360, c = 481
DEBUG_01: a = 320, b = 336, c = 464
DEBUG_01: a = 320, b = 462, c = 562
DEBUG_01: a = 321, b = 428, c = 535
DEBUG_01: a = 322, b = 480, c = 578
DEBUG_01: a = 324, b = 432, c = 540
DEBUG_01: a = 325, b = 360, c = 485
DEBUG_01: a = 327, b = 436, c = 545
DEBUG_01: a = 330, b = 440, c = 550
DEBUG_01: a = 333, b = 444, c = 555
DEBUG_01: a = 336, b = 377, c = 505
DEBUG_01: a = 336, b = 385, c = 511
DEBUG_01: a = 336, b = 448, c = 560
DEBUG_01: a = 339, b = 452, c = 565
DEBUG_01: a = 340, b = 357, c = 493
DEBUG_01: a = 341, b = 420, c = 541
DEBUG_01: a = 342, b = 456, c = 570
DEBUG_01: a = 345, b = 460, c = 575
DEBUG_01: a = 348, b = 464, c = 580
DEBUG_01: a = 351, b = 468, c = 585
DEBUG_01: a = 352, b = 420, c = 548
DEBUG_01: a = 354, b = 472, c = 590
DEBUG_01: a = 357, b = 360, c = 507
DEBUG_01: a = 357, b = 476, c = 595
DEBUG_01: a = 360, b = 378, c = 522
DEBUG_01: a = 360, b = 480, c = 600
DEBUG_01: a = 363, b = 484, c = 605
DEBUG_01: a = 366, b = 488, c = 610
DEBUG_01: a = 368, b = 465, c = 593
DEBUG_01: a = 369, b = 492, c = 615
DEBUG_01: a = 372, b = 496, c = 620
DEBUG_01: a = 375, b = 500, c = 625
DEBUG_01: a = 380, b = 399, c = 551
DEBUG_01: a = 384, b = 440, c = 584
DEBUG_01: a = 390, b = 432, c = 582
DEBUG_01: a = 396, b = 403, c = 565
DEBUG_01: a = 399, b = 468, c = 615
DEBUG_01: a = 400, b = 420, c = 580
DEBUG_01: a = 414, b = 448, c = 610
DEBUG_01: a = 420, b = 441, c = 609
DEBUG_01: a = 429, b = 460, c = 629
DEBUG_01: a = 432, b = 495, c = 657
DEBUG_01: a = 440, b = 462, c = 638
DEBUG_01: a = 460, b = 483, c = 667
DEBUG_01: a = 476, b = 480, c = 676

Antal itererade trianglar: 125250
Antal pytagoreiska trianglar: 456
```

As you can see, whenever I run this I get the answer `456` from the `counter_pyth`, according to my teacher the correct answer is `386` but I don't know what I've done wrong..

#### REVISION 2

```cpp
.
.
.

for (a = 1; a <= 500; a++) {
    for (b = a; b <= 500; b++) {                                        // starts from the same index as 'a' to omit duplicate results
        counter++;
        c = int_sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
        if (c == 100 || c == 200 || c == 300 || c == 400 || c == 500)   // prints the triangles whose hypotenuse matches the integers 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500
            cout << "Triangel med hypotenusan " << c << ": a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;
        if (((a*a)+(b*b))==(c*c)) {
            if (!((a > 500 ) || (b > 500) || (c > 500))) {
                cout << "DEBUG_01: a = " << a << ", b = " << b
                << ", c = " << c << endl;
                counter_pyth++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what happened to the output...

Comment: So... are you getting the right output?

Comment: Yes I formatted it (by adding <br> tags), I'm getting the right output in the console though, it just got garbled when I put it up here (but I've fixed it now)

Comment: But are the numbers correct?

Comment: Yes they should be, I'll check for "obvious" mistakes.

Comment: Then... what's your question? Is it exactly the question that you linked to? If so, please explicitly type it in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally omitted my problem, I'll edit my question now to describe it!

Comment: Please check the end of the answer now (below output), I've described my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Going with the question you linked) Try counting with `c` instead, since `c` must be at most 500 and there is no limit on either `a` or `b`:

```
for(int c = 1; c <= 500; c++) {
    for(int a = 1; a < c; a++) {
        int b = int_sqrt(c * c - a * a);
        if(b > 0) {
            //you've found a right triangle with c at most 500
        }
    }
}
```

You're probably counting more than 386 triangles because you're counting ones with `c > 500`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does it pertain to my problem (see the description below "output" in my question). Note that my program "performs/solves" 2 different "tasks/problems", what I'm interested in is fixing the "amount of pythagorean triangles" problem because the other problem is already solved (the one that "prints the triangles whose hypotenuse matches the integers 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500")

Comment: Because I'm not sure if your answer pertains to my question, I'll remove it if you can provide me with answers that pertain to my question.

Comment: I'll take a look at your answer now and consequently mark your answer as accepted if it is satisfactory!

Comment: I've confirmed that your answer works (although I implemented my own solution, but thanks for helping me figure it out!)
I undid the -1 vote and voted it up, also marked as accepted, thank you!

Comment: I've added my own implementation to the question (under Revision 2), feel free to check it out if you're interested.
Thanks again for the help!